# Has an entire AWS region gone down?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to work out if previous datacenter failures on AWS have just applied to a single "availability zone" or the whole region. Does anyone know the details of the extent of the worst AWS failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon AWS has suffered at least two major outages in its life.

The [first](http://aws.amazon.com/message/65648/), in April of 2011, affected one of the availability zones in US-East.

The [second](https://aws.amazon.com/message/67457/), in June of 2012, affected one of the availability zones in US-East. During this event, for a short period of time it was not possible to start new instances in any US-East availability zone.

Both failures were pretty bad, though they seem to have resolved them pretty well overall.